# How to call javascript from dynamic button in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, dynamic, popup

I am trying to make a popup menu/modal box through Magnific popup plagin.

```
     //Dynamic button:
     Button btn1 = new Button
                    {
                        Text = "Button1"
                    };
     btn1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:return openForm();");

How do you think it is possible to write a script like this:

<script type="text/javascript">
       function openForm() {
             $('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup({
                 type: 'inline',
                 focus: '#name'
             });
           } 
   </script>
```

Or how can I associate a dynamic button with this script?

```
 <!-- The Modal -->
<div id="form-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
 <div runat="server" action="#">
 <div><input id="name" class="inputbox" type="text" placeholder="Your name" /></div>
 <div><input id="email" class="inputbox" type="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" /></div>
 <div><textarea name="mess" id="mess" class="inputbox" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your message"></textarea></div>
 <div><input type="submit" value="Send"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And whether it would be a mistake to do so, replace form with div:

```
<form action="#">     ----->   <div runat="server" action="#">
```

Comment: The information provided here is inadequate to answer. Can you please add more detail.

Comment: Try to change button event with this btn1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "openForm()"); Who is myBtn?

Comment: Bhasyakarulu Kottakota, I edited my answer, Luciano, I checked if the script is called through alert and it work.

Comment: @LUGYAMIR please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-6qdlqt?file=index.html

---

Try these changes.

The popup:

```
<div id="form-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
    <div runat="server" action="#">
      <div><input id="name" class="inputbox" type="text" placeholder="Your name" /></div>
      <div><input id="email" class="inputbox" type="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" /></div>
      <div><textarea name="mess" id="mess" class="inputbox" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your message"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Send"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The popup style:

```
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

The script initialization:

```
$(function () {
  $('#btnOpenPopup').magnificPopup({
    type:'inline',
    closeBtnInside: true
  });
});
```

The dynamic button:

```
  Button btn1 = new Button
      {
        ID = "btnOpenPopup",
        Text = "Button1"
      };
  btn1.Attributes.Add("data-mfp-src", "#form-popup");
```

Plug-in Documentation:

https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

Comment: Thank you for the interesting solution, but unfortunately it hasn’t worked yet

Comment: Through F12 DevTools there are no errors, but when you click on the button there is no reaction. It seems to me that scripts may not connect. I should place the  scripts connection only on the master Page? Or not?

Comment: @LUGYAMIR Yes, references to script and css should be in the main html (it may vary depending on the architecture of the site you are using). Check out the live demo that I added in the answer. Check that everything in your project is like in the demo.

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved it. I just have added CssClass = "btnOpenPopup" to dinamic button

Comment: Yes of course, I voted, but I have less than 15 reputation, so I can't change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Ok thanks, but close to my answer, under the vote, don't you have a gray sign? If you click on it, the answer is accepted as valid for resolution.